# How to find out the amount of rounds per clip before buying a weapon?

Tags: killing-floor

The number of currently loaded rounds/bullets as well as the amount of clips/magazines is visible while playing, but not at the trader. Additionally, it doesn't seem to be visible anywhere at the trader how many bullets per magazine each (non-melee) weapon has.

How can one find how many bullets per magazine each weapon has before buying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sadly, you can't find this out in the trader weapon menu, as it only shows the Speed, Range and Damage of the weapons. If you actually buy the gun, then after you exit the trader interface, you can see how much ammo the weapon has per clip:

[image: Screenshot of the down right corner of the in-game screen]